# How can I get the value of my input before the submit button?

Tags: php

I would Like to get the value of my date input, maybe the solution is Ajax but I don't know ajax at the moment

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="date">Date de réservation</label>
<input class="form-control input-sm datepicker hasDatepicker" name="date"id="date" type="text" value=""></div>
```

and after echo the value in other value here the code

```
<input name="fday" id="fday" value="<?php echo $MyInputvalue ?>" type="hidden">
<input name="fmonth" id="fmonth" value="<?php echo $MyInputvalue ?>" type="hidden">
<input name="fyear" id="fyear" value="<?php echo $MyInputvalue ?>" type="hidden">
```

Comment: You did not yet really understand the separation between server side scripting (php) and client side usage and logic (browser). The moment some date is picked on the client side the server side script has long since terminated, obviously.

Comment: And we need more information: Are both codes on the same page? Do you want to get the value without submitting the form or after doing so? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply GET or POST the value with this:

```
$myDate = $_POST['date']`
```

or

```
$myDate = $_GET['date']
```

There are many differences between them you should check which one suits your needs better. But the main thing you should know is that $_GET shows the value in URL which is not good for passwords and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Use javascript for the same:

`<input class="form-control input-sm datepicker hasDatepicker" name="date"id="date" type="text" value="" onblur="getvalue()"></div>`

`<srcipt>
function getvalue(){
 USE GET ELEMENT BY ID or VALUE HERE.
}
</script>`

This way you can get the value of the input box and later use it anywhere.